# How to prove the following statements about a polynomial ring?

Tags: linear-algebra

Edit: A user told me to split it into three questions, so just pay attention to the first statement here, I don't know if I should delete some questions here yet.

I got the following task from my professor and I wanted to ask for advice from you.

Task:

- $K$ is a field

I shall prove the three following statements:

1. The polynomial ring $K[X]$ is a vector space
2. Prove that for every $v$ element of $K$ the set $I_v = \{\,f \in K[X]\mid f(v) = 0\,\}$ is a linear subspace of $K[X]$.
3. $n \neq v$, $I_n + I_v = K[X]$ and is this a direct sum of modules?

---

My thoughts how to solve the problems:

1. I could use the fact that my polynomial ring is a ring and has already proven axioms which already fulfill all vector space axioms. If I say it's an abelian ring with 1 element. Then it's already an abelian group, and that should do my task pretty quickly if I remember the definition correctly.

   2.. I don't need to prove that much here just that: if p and q are polynoms, $p(v) = 0$ and $q(v) = 0$, $p + q$ is a polynom with $(p+q)(v) = 0$.

Same for the scalar multiplication.

Though I don't know how to write it down here.

3. $f(x) \in K[x]$

What I need to show:

There are $p(x)$ from $I_v$ and $q(x)$ from $I_n$ with $f(x) = p(x) + q(x)$.

$f(x) = (x - v) * a(x) + b(x)$ (Polynomial division)

$s(x) = b(x)/(v - n)$ and $r(x) = a(x) - s(x)$

Then:

$(x - v) * r(x) + (x - n) * s(x)$

$= (x - v) * (a(x) - s(x)) + (x - n) * s(x)$

$= (x - v) * a(x) + (v - n) * s(x)$

$= (x - v) * a(x) + b(x)$

$= f(x)$

$p(x) = (x - v) * r(x)$ and $q(x) = (x - n) * s(x)$

And I think it's not a direct sum.

---

If possible tell me if my thoughts are right and maybe complete my solutions if they are nearly there or give me useful hints?

Comment: I tried to somehow fix this chaotic mess, but it is further very far to be comprehensible. It is really a riddle for me, seemingly you have basic problems using the latin characters, you can't write herein a simple sentence, how can you go to a university to be able to get such problems?

Comment: I'm not an english native speaker and usually don't write about my math problems online so I'm still new to this but still thanks for making my question more bearable

Comment: I am also not native english, but I wouldn't ever sink so deep, to not use shifted characters on the beginning of my sentences, or using points at the end. What the hell do you want? You want other people to solve _your_ problem, and you won't even try to make it so comprehensible for them, as you could?? How the hell do you think it is okay?? What do you think from yourself??

Comment: I thought that would be enough to comprehend my question but I will keep that in mind for the next posts/threads I make in near future here. Now back to the original question, are my thoughts right/correct ?

Comment: I don't know, I also can't decode a single sentence in your question. Anyways, it is not a single question, but 3 different, packaged into one. Never ask multiple questions, because you will get answers only from people knowing the answer for all of them.

Comment: If that's the case I could just edit my question into something like:,,You don't have to answer all three of my questions, one is enough etc." Furthermore I think the first task I wrote (i): The polynomial ring K[X] is a vector space, doesn't seem that hard to understand for me unless my english is that bad. I wrote there my thoughts on the solution:,,I would use the axioms of a commutative ring with 1, since all vector space axioms are already fulfilled there and since we are talking about a polynomial ring I think I can make that assumption etc

Comment: No. Ask this as 3 different, independent questions. It is not a problem here if you ask multiple questions, if they are independent from eachother, and have better look as the s*t of the dogs. If your english grammar is poor, it won't be also a problem until it is comprehensible. But if we can't even decode, where your sentences are starting from, your questions will be closed and deleted.

Comment: Afaik, here is the point coming, when the functional illiterate parasite (=you) gets the info, that if he want others to work instead of him, he also need to move at least one of his fingers. And if he understands this, he goes away, and never come back… you can't imagine, how many times I experienced soon this behavior from people like you.

Comment: Hm I told you about my own thoughts and how I would solve the tasks but since that's apparently not enough I will just wait for another person who might be able to answer my questions and meanwhile think of other solutions to my task and maybe edit my question if I still find something there which is hard comprehend which I apparently don't see. But it's alright I will try to improve so don't worry.

Comment: I helped you, I gave you information, I gave you advices, now I am waiting you to break _your_ question up into 3 independent pieces.

Comment: Since I already made that mistake the only way is to delete this question so that I can make three questions which are independant from each other and I don't think I'm allowed here to create similiar question am I ?

Comment: You could also only remove the 2. and 3. sub-questions, and re-asking them as independently. One thing is important: people should understand all of your questions even if they didn't see the other two.

Comment: That's a good point I didn't think of, thanks.. just wait for a while

Comment: …end every sentence with a single ".". Maybe it is meaningless on your native language, but if you communicate without them, everybody (not only native english speakers, but everybody who learned the latin abc as small child) will think you are illiterate.

Comment: I will have to wait for the third question, since I have to wait for 20 minutes before asking another question. And splitting the task into three seperate questions/threads kinda brings the problem, that if they build up on each other people might not understand them properly and misinterpretate. But that shouldn't be a super big issue here.

Comment: Someone just edited this question when I wanted to delete the other two questions.. I don't know if I should delete them or leave it this way now. And enough of this off-topic chat and thanks for your advices again.