# Polynomial ring: Direct sum of modules?

Tags: linear-algebra

I got the following task from my professor and I wanted to ask for advice from you.

Task:

- $K$ is a field

I shall prove the following statement:

$n \neq v$, $I_n + I_v = K[X]$ and is this a direct sum of modules?

In and Iv are linear subspaces

---

My thoughts on how to solve the problem:

$f(x) \in K[x]$

What I need to show:

There are $p(x)$ from $I_v$ and $q(x)$ from $I_n$ with $f(x) = p(x) + q(x)$.

$f(x) = (x - v) * a(x) + b(x)$ (Polynomial division)

$s(x) = b(x)/(v - n)$ and $r(x) = a(x) - s(x)$

Then:

$(x - v) * r(x) + (x - n) * s(x)$

$= (x - v) * (a(x) - s(x)) + (x - n) * s(x)$

$= (x - v) * a(x) + (v - n) * s(x)$

$= (x - v) * a(x) + b(x)$

$= f(x)$

$p(x) = (x - v) * r(x)$ and $q(x) = (x - n) * s(x)$

And I think it's not a direct sum.

---

If possible tell me if my thoughts are right and maybe complete my solutions if they are nearly right or give me useful hints? Thank you.

Comment: What are $I_n$ and $I_v$?

Comment: They are linear subspaces, I forgot to add them. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: That doesn't explain what $n$ and $v$ denote. I suppose $I_n$ and $I_v$ are not *any* linear subspace.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118063/how-to-prove-the-following-statements-about-a-polynomial-ring . This was the original question I posted but an user told me to split it up into three questions, so to get the whole context I will link you to it.

Comment: I see, it's clearer now.

Comment: @Sai Please, add the necessary context also here so a reader doesn't have to chase for it.

Comment: Then it would be super similiar to the other thread.. Can I just post the link in the question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, $I_n$ and $I_v$ are not only subspaces of the vector space $K[x]$: $K[x]$ is a *commutative ring* and $I_n, I_v$ are *ideals* of this ring, i.e. they are stable for addition and for multiplication by any element of the ring (not only for scalar multiplication).

Indeed, if $p\in I_v$ and $f\in K[x]$, then $(fp)(v)=f(v) p(v)=f(v)\cdot 0=0$, hence $fp\in I_v$, and similarly for $I_n$.

Euclidean division allows for a characterisation of these ideals: we can divide $p(x)$ by $x-v$: we have $$p(x)=q(x) (x-v) +r\quad(r\in K,\enspace q(x)\in K[x]).$$

From this equality, we deduce that $p\in I_v$, i.e. $p(v)=0$ if and only if $r=0$. In other words, $p\in I_v$ if and only if $p$ is divisible by $x-v$.

Similarly, $p\in I_n$ if and only if $p$ is divisible by $x-n$.

So if $p\in I_n\cap I_v$, we can say first $p$ is divisible by $x-v$, which means there exists a polynomial $q$ such that $p(x)=q(x) (x-v)$. Second, $p(n)=q(n)(n-v)=0$. Since $n\neq v$, $n-v\neq 0$ so that $q(n)=0$, which means $q(x)=r(x)(x-n)$  for some polynomial $r$. Hence $$p(x)=r(x)(x-n)(x-v).$$
Conversely, any polynomial that is divisible by $(x-n)(x-v)$ belongs to $I_n\cap I_v$, which proves this intersection is different from $\{0\}$, so that the sum $I_n+I_v$ is *not* direct.

**Another proof**

In any commutative ring $R$, if two ideals $I$ and $J$ are such that $I+J=R$ and the sum is direct, the ideals are generated by *orthogonal idempotents*, i.e. there exists elements $e\in I$, $f\in J$ such that

1. $I=Re$, $J=Rf$.
2. $e^2=e, \quad f^2=f$.
3. $ef=0,\quad 1=e+f$.

However in the ring $K[x]$, which is an integral domain, there exists no other idempotents than $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Thanks alot. THANKS your answer is splendid I would upvote it but I need 15 reputation for that.. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. What's most important is to feel I've been useful!